# Use imported module in other file in other file

Tags: javascript, import, es6-modules

I have a main.js file where i import bootstrap, but for clarity, i import my own bootstrap.js where the real bootstrap imports are. Then i want to use bootstrap scrolSpy in main.js but  dont work.

**main.js**

```
import './bootstrap.js';
var scrollSpy = new ScrollSpy(document.body, {
    target: '#menu'
  })
...
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
import { ScrollSpy } from 'bootstrap';
```

It gaves me an error of no defined ScrollSpy in main.js

So how can i use ScrollSpy in main.js??

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you simply `import { ScrollSpy } from 'bootstrap';` in main.js?

Comment: at the end i will do that, but the main prupose is just import tht file and put, quit comments dependeng the project. So i will not dirt the main file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `./bootstrap.js` you have to export `ScrollSpy`

```
export { ScrollSpy } from 'bootstrap';
```

and in `./main.js` you have to import it

```
import { ScrollSpy } from './bootstrap.js';
var scrollSpy = new ScrollSpy(document.body, {
  target: '#menu'
})
```

Comment: ok. i already think in that, but the clarity in my opinion dissapears. Thanks!!!!!!